# Is there a way to redirect a non-www subdirectory to that subdirectory with the www domain?

Tags: python, django, web-development-server, pythonanywhere, namecheap

I'm new to web hosting and I'm currently having trouble redirecting subdirectories that don't have the www subdomain.

Typing

```
example.com/subdirectory/
```

just goes to

```
https://www.example.com/
```

I want it to go to from

```
example.com/subdirectory/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/subdirectory/
```

I'm using django, pythonanywhere, and namecheap.

I've already looked a lot online but there just doesn't seem to be any examples with someone using django, pythonanywhere and namecheap. There were some cases where using htaccess solved the problem, but I don't think it's compatible with django?

Comment: How are you doing this now?

Comment: I'd guess that you're using namecheap to do the redirect and that they do not include the path in the redirect. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NakedDomains/